# excluding a library during bundle

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I am new to npm, react and webpack but I have a question. In npm how do you prevent a library from being included production package file? 
For example, I am just building a very small component in react and on the site where I am going to place my small component. The problem is Jquery library and bootstrap is already being called in the masterpage of the site and I didn't want to call the same library again in my small application production build but I still want to use them during development(because I am only testing it on local and jquery is not called there). TIA

Appreciate your time ready this and hope I got to learn more from you. By the way I created the app using create-react-app but I already 'ejected' it, so its using the webpack 3

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Webpack externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/)

You can have two webpack configs, on the dev config you include the package as normal, but for your production config add externals for jquery, so it uses the global one already on the page

Comment: Hmm I tried it before it caused an error but weird when I tried it again I think its working now. My package is 30kb smaller compared to before. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The ability you're looking for is named [Code splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html)

[React loadable](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable) may be a good option for you as well